# React.js, using find() to search through the state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, find

I've encountered a problem when trying to find an object in an array of objects(which is also a state) using the find() method. Interestingly when using the same code except when the array of objects is assigned to a constant variable (meaning that it is not a state) everything works fine. I worked on a state as it was, then I worked on a copy of a state but to no avail. Here I'm forwarding the whole React component somewhat simplified for the purpose of this query(originally I'm fetching that array from the server and using one id I want to print other properties of the given object):

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function About() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  const post = [
    { userId: 1, id: 1, title: "sunt", author: "Tom" },
    { userId: 1, id: 2, title: "qui est esse", author: "Tom" },
    { userId: 1, id: 3, title: "ea molestias", author: "Tom" },
    { userId: 1, id: 4, title: "eum et est occaecati", author: "Tom" },
  ];

  const button = <button onClick={() => setPosts(post)}>Click me</button>;
  //id of one of the object
  const ItemId = 2;
  console.log(posts);
  //trying to find the object that has id: 2 an then print other
  //  key -values pairs from that prticular object
  let copyState = [...posts];
  console.log(["state copied"], copyState);
  let bla = copyState.find((item) => item.id === ItemId);
  console.log(bla);
  // pritns: {userId: 1, id: 2, title: "qui est esse",author: "Tom"}

  // console.log(bla.title)
  //prints : undefined

  // console.log(bla.author)
  //prints: undefined
  //console.log(typeof 'bla')
  // prints: string

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>About Page</h1>
      {button}
    </div>
  );
}

export default About;
```

Clicking on the button loads the state and then by uncommenting console.log's errors will start appearing. The first console .log (bla) prints the correct object with has ana id: 3. But then following console.log's are trying to print other properties from that object and that is causing errors. Like I mentioned earlier when doing the same thing but not on a state I was able to access those other properties using dot notation, for example, bla. author and the name 'Tom' was printed on the console. Appreciate any help here, thanks a lot

Comment: thnaks a lot, it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code and works as expected.
Let's check the code:

When the Component renders for the first time, `posts` is set as an empty array.

Then you try to `find` an element from `posts` with `id 2` and store it as `bla` variable.

Since `posts` is empty, `bla` is `undefined`. Then you try to read `title` and `author` property of `bla`, but since `bla` is undefined there you have an error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`.

If you conditionally log properties (example using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)) the code will work and the component renders correctly.
Then, after clicking the button, `posts` state is set to an array of objects, the `find` function will return an object and you logs will show the correct data.

Just another tip: the last console.log: `typeof 'bla'`, should be `typeof bla` without `'`

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause of an error. On render of component `posts` is an empty array and `console.log(bla.title)` try to access title from bla object. So either you need to copy the start after a click or try to use an `optional chaining operator` to access title like `console.log(bla?.title)`

Comment: Thnaks a lot, it helped

Comment: sorry mate it dosent allow me to vote up, apparently I havent earned it yet. I will come back here when i will be able to

Answer (score 0):

On the initial render, the `bla` is null as the `posts` is empty array [].
Handle the case when `find` does not have result by checking for null. Try the snippet.

```js
function About() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = React.useState([]);

  const post = [
    { userId: 1, id: 1, title: "sunt", author: "Tom" },
    { userId: 1, id: 2, title: "qui est esse", author: "Tom" },
    { userId: 1, id: 3, title: "ea molestias", author: "Tom" },
    { userId: 1, id: 4, title: "eum et est occaecati", author: "Tom" },
  ];

  const button = <button onClick={() => setPosts(post)}>Click me</button>;

  
  const ItemId = 2;
  console.log(posts);

  let copyState = [...posts];
  console.log(["state copied"], copyState);

  let bla = copyState.find((item) => item.id === ItemId);
  console.log(bla);

  if (bla) {
    console.log(bla.title)
    console.log(bla.author)
  } else {
    console.log('bla is null/undefined');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>About Page</h1>
      {button}
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<About />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```